# UEFI: Installed Ubuntu only to have Ubuntu freeze at the purple loading screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, uefi

I know this question has been asked but I have tried the solutions to multiple question and yet to have find a working solution.

[This is the photo of the error message after startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjjZe.jpg)

Im sorry that the photo is cropped but I had to in order to meet the 2mb upload limit. I am guessing theres something wrong with my graphics card? Im using a Nvidia gtx 960. The only way i can actually get onto ubuntu in this state is if i set a parameter to the end of the linux line `nouveau.modeset=0`

Comment: The image is 520 KB aprox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that you found the `nouveau.modeset=0` workaround. because that makes this solution a little easier.

Boot with that flag set and log in. Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, search for and open the Additional Drivers app and select the `nvidia-graphics-drivers-361` option. That name will be in parentheses. Hit apply and enter your password to install the driver.

Once you have that driver, you can boot without `nouveau.modeset=0`.

Comment: Thank you so much this finally worked. You have no idea how many things I have tried. The boot up is a bit slow but it doesnt freeze anymore. Again thank you

Comment: Sorry to bother but you did in fact help fix my main issue of freezing but now when booting ubuntu it gets past the load screen but instead of booting up goes back to the grub boot menu...

Comment: Hmm. I think you should ask a new question about that. Remember to include _as much detail as possible_. It makes it easier on us, and gets you a quicker answer, especially if it's complicated question.

Comment: Ok will do then i will make sure to post pictures of the actual errors

Comment: Good luck. __:-)__